# What does 2 mean in middle of batch file?

Tags: batch-file

It's the first time I have to deal with batch file and I faced this line

```
c:\PATH\foocmd 2 "path_to_file.txt" "string"
```

What's the purpose of using 2 in this line?

Answer (score 1):

It's a regular argument to `foocmd`, just like `path_to_file.txt` and  `string`.